Check if an id is already present in a list of mongoose schema ObjectIds
In my node.js project, I have a simple schema that contains the field called likes where I add the users that likes a post:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    likes: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
    }]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('post', postSchema);

When I receive the request, the API has to add the userId to the post and then save it. Before that, I want to check if the userId is in the list. So, I wrote
const postId = req.params.id;
const userId = req.body.userId;

const postToUpdate = await Posts.findById(postId).populate('likes');
if (!postToUpdate.likes.includes(userId)) {
    // code
}

but includes is not a valid function. How can I check if the userId is not already in the likes' list?

includes doesn't work in your case because the likes array stores Mongoose ObjectIds and includes checks object references rather than values. To compare ObjectIds, you need to use the equals method provided by Mongoose.
Please modify your code
const postId = req.params.id;
const userId = req.body.userId;

const postToUpdate = await Posts.findById(postId).populate('likes');
if (!postToUpdate.likes.some(like => like.equals(userId))) {
    // Add userId to the likes array and save the post
    postToUpdate.likes.push(userId);
    await postToUpdate.save();
}

some will iterate over the likes array and use equals to compare the userId properly. This way, you can avoid duplicate likes.

This is common task when working with mongoose arrays. There are a couple of options depending on how you want to approach the task and the examples below assume there will always be a Post with an _id equal to postId.

Use $addToSet. This will only add the ObjectId of userId to the Post.likes array if it doesn't already exist in the array. Probably the cleanest and faster way to achieve the desired outcome in one single db call. If the userId is already in the array then the update does nothing.

const postId = req.params.id;
const userId = req.body.userId;
const postToUpdate = await Posts.findByIdAndUpdate(postId, {
   $addToSet: {
      likes: userId
   }
}, { new: true }); //< new:true just means return the document with the changes (if any)


You can query an array for a single element so just include the userId as part of the query so that if the userId already exists in the likes array then you can quickly carry on with control flow of the application. If it doesn't already exist then you can do an update with $push to add the userId into the array. This is really quick if the userId exists but the downside is that you have make 2 db calls and so is less efficient if it doesn't exist.

const postId = req.params.id;
const userId = req.body.userId;
let postToUpdate = await Posts.findOne({
   _id: postId,
   likes: userId
});
// If nothing was found
if(!postToUpdate){
   postToUpdate = await Posts.findByIdAndUpdate(postId, {
      $push: {
         likes: userId
      }
   }, { new: true });
}

The key point here is that both of these approaches are asynchronous so won't block the event loop, giving better performance in Node.js. That is in contrast to array methods such as Array.some() or Array.includes() or Array.every() which are synchronous and will block the event loop.
